# After trying to install Openvino, an error occurred when using a validation script to verify the installation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openvino

After trying to install Openvino, an error occurred when using a validation script to verify the installation.

```
Cannot create Range layer pool10/global_pooling_reduce_axis id:150
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome Carl. Take a minute and visit [tour] and [ask] :)

Answer (score 0):

We observe similar errors for the squeezenet verification script for OpenVINO Toolkit 2020.4 version. I would advise you to update the OpenVINO version to the latest version 2021.2.